# Minima of symmetric polynomials subject to two symmetric constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, symmetric-functions

The homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree $k$ in $n$ variables is 
$$
f_k(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}.
$$
Consider the following constrained optimization problem: For $k\in\{2,\dots,n\}$,
$$
\text{minimize: }\,\,f_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)
\qquad
\text{ subject to: }\,\, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1\,\, \text{ and }\,\,\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i} = c
$$
for some constant $1\leq c\leq \sqrt{n}$.

I want to characterize the form of the points $\mathbf{x}_{\text{opt}}$ that minimize this.

If $1\leq c\leq \sqrt{k-1}$, the minimum is zero and is achieved by some point of the form $$
\mathbf{x}_{\text{opt}} =(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},0,\dots,0)$$
with $n-k+1$ entries equal to zero.

However if $\sqrt{k-1}\leq c\leq \sqrt{n}$, I don't know what to do. Numerical results show that the minimum will always be achieved by some point of the form
$$
\mathbf{x}_{\text{opt}} = (\underbrace{s,\dots,s}_{m\text{ times}}, \underbrace{t,\dots,t}_{n-m\text{ times}}\Bigr)
$$
for some $s,t\in[0,1]$ and $m\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, where the $m$, $s$, and $t$ will be different depending on $k$ and $c$. That is, the optimal vector will have at most two different elements $s$ and $t$.

But how might I prove this??? Note that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx_i}f_{k}(x_1,\dots,x_n)= f_{k-1}(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)
$$
so my attempt at Lagrange multipliers means that the optimal $\mathbf{x}$ must satisfy
$$
f_{k-1}(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_n) = \lambda \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}} + \mu
$$
for some constants $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and for all $i$. But then I am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be assuming $x_i\ge0$?

Comment: Yes. That should be implicitly assumed, because of the constraint involving $\sqrt{x_i}$.

Comment: I didn't work out the details, but I think a proof should start with the assumption that there are three different $x_i$, then prove that this allows the target function to be reduced while satisfying the constraints. Complications might arise at the boundaries. If it's impossible to have three different values at the minimum, your form for the optimum follows.

Comment: So what you're saying is, hold all but three of the $x_i$'s constant and optimize over those. I should be able to show that those three can't all be different at the optimum? I'll look into it.

Comment: That might work, yes, though what I wrote was more general -- you don't necessarily need to hold the others constant, but that might be a good approach.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using my original interpretation of your comment, holding $x_4,\dots,x_d$ constant and varying only over $x_1,x_2,x_3$. I was originally going to post it as a comment, but it ended up far too long and made it an answer instead. It doesn't completely solve the problem though. I still need to check the boundaries.  Does my partial answer look ok so far?

Comment: @joriki Do you have any more suggestions? I think I'm pretty close, but I'm stuck. I'd like to show the following: If $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are nonzero and distinct, then the LHS of (4) in the answer is not equal to zero.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer Have you considered the complementary slackness conditions? Given the symmetry of your objective, they might lead to the hypothesized form.

Answer (score 0):

(At the moment, this is not a complete answer. It is only my attempt to prove something I suggested in the comments.)

**Theorem 1**. 
*If $\vec{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a minimum, then at least one of $x_i$ is zero or  the entries of $\vec{x}$ take at most two distinct values.*

The result of the Theorem will follow directly from the following lemma.

**Lemma 2**. *If $x_4,\dots,x_n$ are held constant and we optimize only over $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, a critical point of $f_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ cannot be achieved if either one of $x_1$, $x_2$ or $x_3$ is zero or $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are all different.*

*Proof.*  Consider holding $x_4,\dots,x_n$ constant and varying over $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ subject to 
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
x_1+x_2+x_3 = X 
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3} = C.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
For a fixed $x_1$, there is only one possible choice for $x_2$ and $x_3$ (up to a permutation of $x_2$ and $x_3$), and these values vary analytically as $x_1$ changes. Taking the derivatives of \eqref{eq1} with respect to $x_1$, we find
$$
1+\frac{dx_2}{dx_1} + \frac{dx_3}{dx_1} = 0  \qquad\text{ and }\qquad \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2}}\frac{dx_2}{dx_1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_3}}\frac{dx_3}{dx_1} = 0. 
$$
Solving for $\frac{dx_2}{dx_1}$ and $\frac{dx_3}{dx_1}$ we find
$$
\frac{dx_2}{dx_1} = \frac{\sqrt{x_2}}{\sqrt{x_1}}\frac{\sqrt{x_3}-\sqrt{x_1}}{\sqrt{x_2}-\sqrt{x_3}}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\frac{dx_3}{dx_1} = \frac{\sqrt{x_3}}{\sqrt{x_1}}\frac{\sqrt{x_2}-\sqrt{x_1}}{\sqrt{x_3}-\sqrt{x_2}}.
$$
Note that we can write
\begin{align}
f_k(x_1,\dots,x_n) =& x_1x_2x_3 f_{k-3}(x_4,\dots,x_n)\\
                    &\qquad + (x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3) f_{k-2}(x_4,\dots,x_n) \\ 
                    &\qquad+ \underbrace{(x_1+x_2+x_3)}_{=X}f_{k-1}(x_4,\dots,x_n) + f_{k}(x_4,\dots,x_n) .\tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}
The last line in \eqref{eq2} is constant. Taking the derivative of the entire expression in \eqref{eq2} with respect to $x_1$, we find
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx_1}f_k(\vec{x}) =
  &         \left(x_2x_3+x_1x_2\frac{dx_3}{dx_1} + x_1x_3\frac{dx_3}{dx_1} \right)f_{k-3}(x_4,\dots,x_n) + \left(x_2+x_3+(x_1+x_3)\frac{dx_2}{dx_1} + (x_1+x_2)\frac{dx_3}{dx_1} \right)f_{k-2}(x_4,\dots,x_n)\nonumber\\
  =&  \frac{\left(\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_3}\right)\left(\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_2}\right)}{\sqrt{x_1}}\bigl(\sqrt{x_1x_2x_3} f_{k-3}(x_4,\dots,x_n) - \left(\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}\right)f_{k-2}(x_4,\dots,x_n)\bigr)\tag{3}\label{eq3}.
\end{align}
There is a critical point if and only if the derivative in \eqref{eq3} vanishes. If we suppose that $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are all non-zero and distinct, then the derivative in \eqref{eq3} will vanish if and only if 
$$
\sqrt{x_1x_2x_3} f_{k-3}(x_4,\dots,x_n) - \bigl(\underbrace{\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}}_{=C}\bigr)f_{k-2}(x_4,\dots,x_n) = 0. \tag{4}\label{eq4}
$$
HOWEVER... This is where I get stuck. It still needs to be shown that \eqref{eq4} cannot vanish if $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are all nonzero and distinct.

Furthermore, it can be shown that on the boundary of the allowable points $x_1,x_2,x_3$, either one of them is zero or two of them are equal.

Hence, if all of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are nonzero and distinct, then that point is NOT a minimum since it is neither a boundary point nor a critical point.

It follows that, if $\vec{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a minimum then at least one of $x_i$ is zero, or the entries of $\vec{x}$ take at most two distinct values.